# How to clear search under pages if pasted a big content by mistake?

Tags: error, search

By mistake, I pasted a big piece of content in the search bar. I'm unable to clear the search. It keeps loading and I get this error. "Magento2 Error: "Something went wrong with processing the default view and we have restored the filter to its original state" how do I clear this.s

Answer (score 0):

You have to delete an entry from the ui_bookmark table.
In a ui_bookmark table, delete the row where you want to reset the filter.

Please follow below steps to resolve the issue.

1. Login phpmyadmin and select magento database
2. Find ui_bookmark table and Truncate/Empty the table,[image: Check Here]
3. After that Clear cache
4. Reload error page .

I Hope It Works For You.